# Error while updating opp

Tags: trigger

For the below code, i am getting duplicate id in list error in line 19 -

```
public class DFCS_SyncOppStageWithQuote
{

  public static set<ID> OppIdClosedWon = new set<ID>();
  public static set<ID> OppIdClosedLost = new set<ID>();
   public static list<Quote_Information__c> listToUpdate=new list<Quote_Information__c>() ;
public static void SyncMethodForStage(List<Opportunity> OppList)
  {

     for(Opportunity Opp:OppList)
     {
         If(Opp.StageName=='Closed Won')
         {  
         system.debug('Opp.StageName+'+ Opp.StageName);
         OppIdClosedWon.add(Opp.id);
         }
     }

  set<Quote_Information__c> OppListNew = new set<Quote_Information__c>([select Id,name,Quote_Stage__c 
                                                               from Quote_Information__c
                                                               where Opportunity__c in:OppIdClosedWon]);

   system.debug('OppListNew data+'+ OppListNew);
   for(Quote_Information__c Opp1:OppListNew )
   {
     Opp1.Quote_Stage__c='Closed Won';
     listToUpdate.add(Opp1);
     system.debug('listToUpdate%%%'+ listToUpdate);

   } 
      Update listToUpdate;

  }


}
```

I am not able to identify the miss. Please advice.

Comment: Why you are using set<Quote_Information__c> OppListNew for querying result, instead use advance for loop and make your for loop iterate over list of  Quote_Information__c , for(Quote_Information__c Opp1: [Select Id,... From Quote_Information__c ] ), because one opportunity can have multiple  Quote_Information__c in relation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting the error in the line:

```
Update listToUpdate;
```

This is not a good way to manage the list:

```
 public static list<Quote_Information__c> listToUpdate=new list<Quote_Information__c>() ;
```

because if the `SyncMethodForStage` is called more than once you have the risk of adding duplicate values to the already populated list. It is generally better to use a local variable - just defined inside the `SyncMethodForStage` method - that is setup each time the method is called. (The same applies for `OppIdClosedWon`.)

Also the standard way to avoid duplicate records in collections is to use the object Id as a map key (and map has a convenient constructor for that):

```
Map<Id, Quote_Information__c> opps = new Map<Id, Quote_Information__c>([
        select Id,name,Quote_Stage__c 
        from Quote_Information__c
        where Opportunity__c in:OppIdClosedWon
        ]);
for (Quote_Information__c opp : opps.values()) {
    opp.Quote_Stage__c = 'Closed Won'
}
update opps.values();
```

This eliminates the need for the `listToUpdate` variable.